# cycle use bufio.NewReader(os.stdin) and session.Run(Cmd),the second，I need to press Enter twice, why?

Tags: go, ssh

I want to write a Go SSH client that can only use specific commands. I've written a function for a looped session, but I've noticed that during the second run, it requires hitting Enter once before entering the command for it to take effect. Why is that?

```golang
var commandList = map[string]bool{
    "ls":    true,
    "ls -l": true,
    "date":  true,
}

func CircularSession(c *ssh.Client) {
    var Cmd string
    for {
        session, err := c.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("create session failed：", err)
        }

        session.Stdout = os.Stdout
        session.Stdin = os.Stdin
        session.Stderr = os.Stderr

        fmt.Print("\nPlease enter the command: ")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        Cmd, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
        Cmd = strings.TrimSpace(Cmd)

        if Cmd == "exit" {
            os.Exit(0)
            break
        } else {
            if _, exists := commandList[Cmd]; exists {
                err = session.Run(Cmd)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("command run failed: ", err)
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Println("This command is not supported.")
            }
        }



// other code 
        c := sshconnect.GetSshClient()
        sshconnect.CircularSession(c)
```

If I use an unsupported command, like `ls -lah`, it returns `This command is not supported.`, and then I only need to press Enter once for it to succeed, just like the first run.

I've added `fmt.Println()` before and after `session.Run()`, but it doesn't work; I still need to press Enter twice.

How do I modify it?

Comment: Maybe because you're using `bufio` which–as it name says–uses buffered IO: it may read and buffer more data that what is returned / used by you.